# leaderboard with persistent data in swift using usersdefault to save the values

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to create a leaderboard, but the player names and scores are not permanently saved, the "leaderboard" only contains the data from the most recent game in its text view. I tried making arrayOfData initially hold playerName and finalScore instead of being an empty array, but the problem still remains. How can I display playerName and playerScore in the leaderboard permanently and hove more names and scores added as more people play?

```
var finalScore = Int()
var playerName = String()
var allMyStoredData = UserDefaults.standard
var arrayOfData: [Any] = []
class secondVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var nameTF: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var doneButton: UIButton!
var playerScore = 0
var arrayOfData: [Any] = []
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        scoreLabel.text = "Your score is: \(finalScore)"
        loadData()
}

@IBAction func donePressed(_ sender: Any) {
    saveData()
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toLeaderboard", sender: self)
}

func saveData () {
    playerName = nameTF.text!
    playerScore = finalScore
    arrayOfData.append(playerName)
    arrayOfData.append(playerScore)
    allMyStoredData.set(playerName, forKey: "saveTheName")
    allMyStoredData.set(playerScore, forKey: "saveTheScore")
    allMyStoredData.set(arrayOfData, forKey: "saveTheArray")


}

func loadData () {
    if let loadPlayerName:String = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "saveTheName") as? String {
        playerName = loadPlayerName
    }

    if let loadTheScore:Int = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "saveTheName") as? Int {
        playerScore = loadTheScore
    }
}

}
```

//this is the code in the leaderboard's view controller

```
class leaderboardViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var theTextView: UITextView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        theTextView.text = "\((arrayOfData).map{"\($0)"}.joined(separator: "          Score: "))"
    }

}
```

Comment: I would suggest using coreData to store your data. UserDefaults isn't meant to store large amounts of data. coreData has a learning curve, but is much more scalable since it's an actual database.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your `saveTheArray` item `UserDefaults` each time with a new array.

You want to fetch the saved array first, append the new game data, then re-save as so:

```
//Create user defaults instance
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

//User defaults key
let historicalGameDataKey = "historicalGameData"

//Fetch game data array
var historicalGameData = userDefaults.array(forKey: historicalGameDataKey)

//Create array if it is nil (i.e. very first game)
if historicalGameData == nil {
    historicalGameData = []
}

//Create game data dictionary
let gameData = [
    "playerName": playerName,
    "playerScore": playerScore
]

//Append game data dictionary to the array
historicalGameData?.append(["playerName": gameData])

//Save the updated array
userDefaults.set(historicalGameData, forKey: historicalGameDataKey
```

Core Data would be a better way to store this data, but this example should solve your problem using UserDefaults.